# MS Access invalid syntax

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access 2007 The code below gives Error 2434: The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.

```
  If (Eval("DLookUp(""[BaseRate]"",""RATELOOKUP"",""|DatePart(""yyyy"",[TxDate])| & |DatePart(""m"",[TxDate])| = [RATELOOKUP].[PERIOD]"") Is Null")) Then
        ' Checks for Current Base Rate
        Beep
        MsgBox "Interest Rate required for this month", vbExclamation, ""
    End If
```

The error appears to be in the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper quoting within the string expression you give to `Eval()` can be very challenging.  Here is what `Eval()` actually sees within your code:

```
DLookUp("[BaseRate]","RATELOOKUP","|DatePart("yyyy",[TxDate])| & |DatePart("m",[TxDate])| = [RATELOOKUP].[PERIOD]") Is Null
```

Consider a different approach when using `Eval()`, one which allows you to see exactly what you're asking `Eval()` to evaluate.

```
Dim strEval As String
strEval = "your expression here"
Debug.Print strEval ' <- examine the string Eval() receives
' finally ...
If Eval(strEval) ...
```

However, this thing looks way too complicated to me, so I suspect there should be a simpler solution which doesn't even require `Eval()`.  Unfortunately your `DLookup` *Criteria* argument is so confusing I got lost.  But I suspect the `IsNull()` function might give you what you want without needing `Eval()`:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("BaseRate","RATELOOKUP", "your Criteria here")) = True Then
```

Comment: Thanks. At least you've narrowed the issue down to the criteria string. I know what it's trying to do but I don't know enough about Access SQL syntax to know how to rewrite it. Fortunately, it turns out that removing the code works well enough provided the client sets the interest rate (which he always does) so the validation can be bypassed without the world exploding.